# How to Implement Localization for Azure Adb2c (Custom Policy) In flutter (dart)?

Tags: azure, flutter, oauth, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to implement a localization for Azure Adb2c in Flutter, in angular localization is implemented using `ui_locales = language` in configuration, I can't achive this in Flutter `aad_oauth`. Is there any other ways to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

To add localization in flutter, By default Flutter only provides US English localizations. To add support for other languages, an application must specify additional MaterialApp (or CupertinoApp) properties, and include a package called flutter_localizations
To use flutter_localizations, add the package as a dependency to your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations: 
    sdk: flutter
```

Next, run pub get packages, then import the flutter_localizations library and specify localizationsDelegates and supportedLocales for MaterialApp:

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
```

and then add your code.
If you want to use your own localized messages first add the flutter_localizations  and then Add the intl package to the pubspec.yaml file:

Comment: I tried to implement localization for `Azure ADB2C` in Flutter, i have implemented localization in App successfully using `flutter_localizations`. I have used `aad_oauth` for User authentication. In `aad_oauth` i cant achive localization